# How to call checkSelfPermission(android.content.Context,java.lang.String) from inner class

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, runtime-permissions

I am trying to invoke the method `ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permissionfrom)` inside an inner class. Outer class is inherited from `android.app.Activity`and inner class is not an inherited class. My problem is what variable should I give for the first argument `context` in the method. 
I am new to android and couldn't find a solid answer for this. if call the method inside the outer class, `this` can be used as an argument? But, what happens if I invoke the method inside the inner class ?

Comment: `OuterActivityClass.this` - if your outer class is `MainActivity` then use `MainActicity.this`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(YourActivityName.this, permissionfrom)`, like this. Here, `YourActivityName` should be replaced by your Outer class name.

Comment: Yamini - Here, the outer class should be extended from `android.app.Activity`. Isn't it ? (In  my case yes) But just need a clarification ? Apart from that, in order to use the method `requestPermissions(android.app.Activity,java.lang.String[],int)` the outer class should implements `OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback`.Is it ?

Comment: @ShaAk No. The outer class doesn't need to implements OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback. If you extend AppCompatActivity to your class, you can just use it, since it is available already.

Comment: What about the outer class is extended from `android.app.Activity` ? Not from `AppCompatActivity` ?

Answer (score 0):

Pass as context- {name of your outer class}.this

Hope this helps